# Why is the viewport DoF glitching?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

When I try to use the viewport DoF the viewport just seizes up and when I try to zoom in and out I get this effect, could this be due to an outdated gpu? I'm using Blender 2.76, this was happening with 2.75 as well.

[image]

Comment: What GPU do you have?

Comment: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 series

Comment: I tried enabling the settings I saw in your screen shot (Focus:Empty, Composition Guides?, F-stop 2.8, Imperial measurement units) but I couldn't reproduce it. Might help if we could take a look at the .blend, even if you simplify it by removing objects, etc. Also, does the glitch persist even after you Load Factory Settings? This might be the kind of thing to file directly in a bug report.

Comment: The glitch still occurs after loading the factory settings. Also, this happens with any .blend, even if it's just the default scene so I don't think that it's a problem with the .blend. It may be my GPU's compatibility, I do have a fairly outdated GPU.